# Response.End in PHP

Tags: php, equivalent

Is there any equivalent to `Response.End` in PHP?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
exit();
die();
flush();
```

Comment: Note that `flush` *doesn’t end* the response. It empties the response buffer, but continues to write to it.